# Calling JAVA Method from XQuery

Tags: xquery

I am trying to call a JAVA method from XQuery. But it is failing

I have declared the class like:

```
declare namespace b64 = "java:java.util.Base64";
```

And I am calling it like:

```
(: Encode a string into Base64 :)
declare function javautil:encodebase64($in as xs:string) as xs:string {
    b64:getEncoder().encodeToString($in)
};

(: Decode a string from Base64 :)
declare function javautil:decodebase64($in as xs:string) as xs:string {
    b64:getDecoder().decode($in)
};
```

But I get the error:

```
XPST0003: XQuery syntax error in #...64:getEncoder().encodeToString#:
expected "}", found "."
```

I am not sure if its a syntax problem or something else. I looked for examples on Google. But most of them are restricted to a single method call. Not chained method like `getEncoder().encodeToString()`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which XQuery processor are you using?  If you are just trying to do base 64 encoding/decoding as in the example, several XQuery processors have modules to do this.

Comment: @DavidDenenberg I am using Saxon and a very old one at that. And XQ version 1.0 if that matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing Java syntax with XQuery syntax - there's no "." operator in XQuery.

In XQuery 1.0 I would expect to see `b64:decode(b64:getDecoder(), $in)`, or in XQuery 3.1 `b64:getDecoder() => b64:decode($in)`